# TabbedPane iterate for loop

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jtabbedpane

I received in loop iteration as:

```
Tab 1
Tab 2
```

On beginning code I have panel, tabbedpane and scrollpane:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
JScrollPane scrollPanel = new JScrollPane();
```

Then receive through iteration using Event JList and receive `Tab 1` and `Tab 2`, but can't add two tabs. So here is iterate and receive `Tab 1` and `Tab 2` into `tab_name` variable:

```
String tab_name = ap_data_array[2]; // Tab 1, Tab 2

tabbedPane.addTab(tab_name, panel); // Here add only once tab Tab 1
this.jPanel1.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

scrollPanel.setViewportView(new JLabel(ap_data_array[2]));
tabbedPane.setBounds(0, 0, 530, 500);

this.jPanel1.setSize(530,500);

System.out.println(tab_name); // Tab 1 then Tab 2
```

A result will only render 1 tab, `Tab 1`.

Here is full code:

```
String lines[] = loaded_data.split("\\r?\\n");
for (String item : lines)
{
String pattern = "AP.*";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(item);

// Added
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
JScrollPane scrollPanel = new JScrollPane();

if (m.find())
{
    String ap_data = m.group(0);
    String[] ap_data_array = ap_data.split("\\|", -1);



    if (ap_data_array[0].equals("AP"))
    {
        JList source = (JList)evt.getSource();
        String selected = source.getSelectedValue().toString();

        // type selected
        if (ap_data_array[1].equals(selected))
        {
            // tabs name
            //ap_data_array[2]  // "Tab 1" "Tab 2"

            String tab_name = ap_data_array[2];

            tabbedPane.addTab(tab_name, panel);
            this.jPanel1.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

            scrollPanel.setViewportView(new JLabel(ap_data_array[2]));
            tabbedPane.setBounds(0, 0, 530, 500);



            this.jPanel1.setSize(530,500);

            System.out.println(tab_name); // "Tab 1" "Tab 2"
     }
     }
}
}
```

---

**SOLUTION:**

```
    private void jList1ValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                    

    if (evt.getValueIsAdjusting())
    {
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();

        this.jPanel1.removeAll(); // REMOVE ALL DATA IN PANEL TO RELOAD NEW TAB PANEL IN LOOP

        String lines[] = loaded_data.split("\\r?\\n");
        for (String item : lines)
        {
            String pattern = "AP.*";
            Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
            Matcher m = r.matcher(item);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();

            if (m.find())
            {
                String ap_data = m.group(0);
                String[] ap_data_array = ap_data.split("\\|", -1);



                if (ap_data_array[0].equals("AP"))
                {
                    JList source = (JList)evt.getSource();
                    String selected = source.getSelectedValue().toString();

                    // type selected
                    if (ap_data_array[1].equals(selected))
                    {
                        String tab_name = ap_data_array[2]; // STRING "Tab 1" and "Tab 2" loop


                        this.jPanel1.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                        tabbedPane.add(tab_name, new JLabel(tab_name));

                        tabbedPane.setBounds(0, 0, 530, 500);

                        this.jPanel1.setSize(530,500);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: if you receive only two items in array why are you indexing to `ap_data_array[2]`?

Comment: There is above iteration, `ap_data_array[2]` receive only string `Tab 1` for example.

Comment: so what is the expected output that you want?

Comment: I've received `Tab 1` in first loop and then render only one tab, then in next iteration comes `Tab 2` as string and should add tab using `addTab()` function but it will not render only one tab.

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: Problem might be you are adding tab to `jPanel1` instead of `jPanel`

Comment: `jPanel1` is fixed JPanel control that render tabs. A name is jPanel1. So this is okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly (no guarantee since it's not a [minimal example program](http://sscce.org) that I can run and test), inside of the for loop you're creating a **new JTabbedPane** with each iteration, adding a single tab to it, and then adding it to a BorderLayout-using JPanel in the BorderLayout.CENTER position. Thus if you iterate twice, you will create two JTabbedPanes, each with only one tab, and the second one will completely cover the first one. If this is indeed the source of your problems then the solution is easy: create only **one** JTabbedPane, do this **before** the for loop, and add your tabs (JPanels) inside the for loop.

Other problems include your use of `setBounds(...)`. Don't do this.

Comment: I think this is possible answer, i will check it.

Comment: Found a solution. Should be: `this.jPanel1.add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                            tabbedPane.add(tab_name, new JLabel(tab_name));` instead of `addTab()` function.